# Haskell: No instance for (Show Exp) arising from a use of 'print'

Tags: haskell

I am getting the following error:

No instance for (Show Exp) arising from a use of ‘print’

In the expression: print ti1

In an equation for ‘it’: it = print ti1

---

When I

```
ghci>ti1 = Add (Lit 8) (Neg (Add (Lit 1) (Lit 2)))
ghci>print ti1
```

My entire code is:

```
data Exp = Lit Int
    | Neg Exp
    | Add Exp Exp
    
view:: Exp -> String
view (Lit n) = show n
view (Neg e) = "(-" ++ view e ++ ")"
view (Add e1 e2) = "(" ++ view e1 ++ " + " ++ view e2 ++ ")"
```

---

How can I print this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I print this string?

You should call the `view` function first, so:

```
ghci> ti1 = Add (Lit 8) (Neg (Add (Lit 1) (Lit 2)))
ghci> print (view ti1)
"(8 + (-(1 + 2)))"
```

But it sufficient to just call `view`, since it will automatically print the result in ghci:

```
ghci> ti1 = Add (Lit 8) (Neg (Add (Lit 1) (Lit 2)))
ghci> view ti1
"(8 + (-(1 + 2)))"
```

You can furthermore make the `view` function the `show` function for `Exp`:

```
instance Show Exp where
    show = view
```

then it is sufficient to just query for `t1`, or `print t1`:

```
ghci> print ti1
(8 + (-(1 + 2)))
ghci> ti1
(8 + (-(1 + 2)))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer for a very new haskell user :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your data declaration derive the `Show` instance. So change your data declaration to:

```
data Exp = Lit Int
    | Neg Exp
    | Add Exp Exp deriving (Show)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer but I will choose the other answer since it does not require a change in my code